# Angular App in Nginx Docker. How to enable SSL?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, ssl, https

I deployed an Angular App inside of Nginx Docker. Everything works fine until the moment when I tried to set up SSL.

I have enter into the running container and I tried to create certificate with certbot.

```
docker exec -it <container_name> sh

certbot --nginx -d dev.mydomain.com -d www.mydomain.com
enter code here
```

I have got notification from cert-bot that certificates are successfully installed.
I am still not able to reach https and from the moment I finished all tasks with cert-bot I can't even reach via http.

I set up Firewall on the DigitalOcean Server to accept HTTPS and HTTP and also I payed attention on ports 22 and 443.

I am using this Dockerfile to generate docker image and later to run docker container.

```
FROM nginx:1.20-alpine
RUN apk add python3 python3-dev py3-pip build-base libressl-dev musl-dev libffi-dev rust cargo
RUN pip3 install pip --upgrade
RUN pip3 install certbot-nginx
RUN mkdir /etc/letsencrypt
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /dist/myapp /usr/share/nginx/html
```

default.conf

```
server {
listen       80;
listen  [::]:80;
server_name  dev.mydomain.com;

#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

}

After certbot finishes his work my default.conf is filled with certificates and redirection and everything that should be there for ssl.

Still I am not able to use HTTPS.

anyone with advice? Help ? Is it maybe better to deploy app on NGINX Server not on Docker ?

This is what I got when certbot install certificate. Everything seems fine but still no results...
[image]